# BLE advertising interval for Fitbits?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, fitbit

I'm working with Fitbit devices, specifically the Charge HR, and I was wondering how often the device sends out BLE advertising packets.  I can't seem to find anything about this in the Fitbit Dev forum, nor here on Stackoverflow, and unfortunately I don't have an actual Charge HR device available right now.  Does anyone know?  Is there documentation somewhere?

Comment: This would be some useful information. From my observations (over the last 20 minutes) it seems very random. It seems to broadcast more often while syncing with my iPhone's Fitbit app (a couple of times a second then nothing for 5-10 seconds then repeat). With the same scanning program I couldn't pick up anything from the charge hr yesterday (but I wasn't interacting with the HR at all).

Comment: It broadcasts more often?  The only info I've been able to find on this is that when a Fitbit pairs with a phone (I assume when it syncs), according to a moderator on the Fitbit developer forum it should stop advertising.  It's here: https://community.fitbit.com/t5/Web-API/Charge-HR-and-Bit-Finder-Geo-app/m-p/1106648#M4177.  It's interesting that you found it broadcasts more often.  I will have to get one and do some experiments with it.

Comment: Its advertisements seem very random. Booting up the same scanning program today shows no advertisements from the Charge HR regardless of whether it is trying to sync or not.
It is possible that there was a problem with the pairing between the phone and the device when I made my last comment. I re-paired it yesterday which might be the reason it is not advertising anymore (which seems more in line with the information in your link).